# reading from text file in c++ at certain offset

Tags: c++, c, matrix

I have a diagonally dominant matrix with size 16000 * 16000. I want to extract the first n rows and n columns of this matrix for my experiment(for example the first 100*100 cells) so that the extracted matrix is still diagonal dominant.My attempt to do that is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main()
{

double **Matrix_A;
FILE *fp;   
int global_size = 100;
int offset = 0;

if ((fp = fopen ( "matrix_16000.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
               printf("Can't open input matrix file");
               exit(-1);
             }

 Matrix_A = (double **) malloc(global_size*sizeof(double *));
 for(int irow = 0; irow < global_size; irow++)
    {
    offset =  irow * 16000;
    fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);
    Matrix_A[irow] = (double *) malloc(global_size * sizeof(double));
    for(int icol = 0; icol < global_size; icol++){
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &Matrix_A[irow][icol]);

        }

    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
 }
```

This will not work because offset is not fixed since matrix is generated at random. Any better idea knowing that my compiler is mpicc

Comment: mpicc isnt a compiler, its a wrapper around one of a number of compilers... This also isnt a minimal compilable example

Comment: The code is very long .. this is just an extract. I mean when running my code, I just use mpicc command with default options.

Comment: @Nawal So, **manufacture** [mcve]. Why should we invest our time into helping you, if you can't even be bothered to make an example we can use?

Comment: It is next to impossible to travel to a particular offset in a text file and get the data you want. The size of the tokens in the file are often irregular. My suggestion, since you've tagged C++ and you wouldn't have to `(double **) malloc` if you were actually compiling for C is to use `std::ifstream`, `std::getilne` a line, stuff the line into a `std::istringstream`, use `>>` to read the first 100 (or whatever's chosen) elements from the line into a slot in a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, and then repeat for the next 99 lines.

Comment: This is slow, you're better off using a a single vector that's been mapped into a 2D matrix, but it's dead easy to use and get started. You can optimize the data structure for speed after you have a working program.

Comment: `fseek()` for text files has implementation defined behaviour unless `offset` is zero or a value returned by `ftell()`.   It is also an offset in bytes, not in something the size of a `double`.

Comment: Is this c or c++?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually very close.  fseek isn't going to work; instead, scan to the EOL:

```
 int c;
 Matrix_A = (double **) malloc(global_size*sizeof(double *));
 for(int irow = 0; irow < global_size; irow++) {
    Matrix_A[irow] = (double *) malloc(global_size * sizeof(double));
    for(int icol = 0; icol < global_size; icol++){
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &Matrix_A[irow][icol]);
    }
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\r' && c != '\n') {}
 }
 fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Can I talk you into replacing 13 and 10 with '\r' and '\n'? Easier to interpret the intent.

Comment: @Charlie Loads of (avoidable), malloc(), but no free().

Comment: Sure I will clean it up.  I'm just trying to illustrate the important bit, which is seeking to EOL.

Comment: I'm keeping the malloc() w/o free(), because that's the data structure the poster wanted.  He did say "C++", but the code is "C"; I am sticking with that paradigm.  There are, of course, much better data structures using STL.